# zf2 zend routing get request parameters with $this->params()->fromQuery() not working

Tags: parameters, routes, request, zend-framework2

i have added this zf2 route config to the standard skeleton application:
(edit: here my complete config:)

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'test' => array(
                'type'    => 'literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/test',
                    'defaults' => array(
                           'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                           'action'     => 'test',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes'  => array(
                    'query' => array(
                        'type' => 'Query',
                        'options' => array(
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'testparam' => 'bar'
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),    
        ),

        // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
        // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
        // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
        // using the path /application/:controller/:action
        'application' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/application',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            //'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),

    ),
),
```

in the controller i want to do get the request parameters within the testAction:
(edit: here my complete controller):

```
    namespace Application\Controller;

    use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
    use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

    class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
    {
        public function indexAction()
        {
            var_dump(
                    $this->params()->fromQuery(),
                    $this->getRequest()->getQuery(),
                    $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParams()
             );

            return new ViewModel();
        }

        public function testAction(){
            var_dump(
                    $this->params()->fromQuery(),
                    $this->getRequest()->getQuery(),
                    $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParams()
             );

            return new ViewModel();
        }
    }
```

**URL:**    `/test?testparam=123123`
**RESULT:** PARAM IS NOT OK! HERE I WOULD EXPECT PARAM TO BE "123123"
if i remove may_terminate then i get

```
PARAM = "bar" (see default value for "testparam")

array(0) { } object(Zend\Stdlib\Parameters)#195 (1) { ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=> array(0) { } } array(3) { ["controller"]=> string(28) "Application\Controller\Index" ["action"]=> string(4) "test" ["testparam"]=> string(3) "bar" }
```

**URL:**    `/?testparam=123123`
**RESULT:** PARAM IS OK!

```
array(1) { ["testparam"]=> string(6) "123123" } object(Zend\Stdlib\Parameters)#88 (1) { ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=> array(1) { ["testparam"]=> string(6) "123123" } } array(2) { ["controller"]=> string(28) "Application\Controller\Index" ["action"]=> string(5) "index" }
```

neither of these works i only receive NULL values with this URL: `/test?testparam=testvalue`

if i make this request it works: `/?xxx=xycvxcv`

(but i need to get the params from within the `testAction()`)

i did make a fresh install of the skeleton application --> same result (only within the `indexAction` ("home-route") it was possible to get the request parameters ...

Answer (score 0):

The First And Second method should works for you if you using flowing routing :

```
'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

**URL :  `http://localhost/project/public/?ad=23`**

var_dump :

> array   'ad' => string '23' (length=2)
>
> object(Zend\Stdlib\Parameters)[106]   public 'ad' => string '23'
>   (length=2)

**EDIT ** : Maybe you should remove 'may_terminate' clause from array

Comment: the "home" definition above is already in the default skeleton

Comment: i've updated the description of the problem ... my problem arises if the url looks like this: URL: http://localhost/project/public/test?ad=23

Answer (score -1):

```
   The Query qoute part (Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Query) is deprectaed
    change your config to look like this 
     'test' => array(
                'type'    => 'literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/test',
                    'defaults' => array(
                           'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                           'action'     => 'test',
                    ),
                )
```